# How to use frame animation similar to UIKIT in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I'm just using swiftUI.
I want some one view to have a repeating animation: 1.move up, 2.pause, 3.move up, 4.pause, 5.move down, 6.pause, 7.move down, 8.pause.

Similar to the undulations of pixel wind in Contra.

In UIkit, I can use `UIView.animateKeyframes` in the block to make the view change.Specify anywhere.
In swfitUI I don't know how to do.

can anyone help me？

I have understood that it is not simply moving the y-axis that can achieve the pixel wind effect.

```
VStack {
                Text("❤️")
                .font(.system(size: 200,weight: .bold))
                .offset(y: offsetY)
                .onAppear{
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true) { _ in
                        animate()
                    }
                }
}



 func animate() {
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
            self.offsetY -= 10
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
                self.offsetY -= 10
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.offsetY = 0
        }
    }
```

Ask about the code obtained after ChatGPT modification,I always feel weird.

1. I think it should not be done in onAppear block
2. If I want to specify any view to animate in a method, what should I do?
   swiftUI cannot

```
let customView =  Text("❤️")


func somMethod(){
     customView use animate
}
```

Comment: Please provide explanation (or gif) of „undulations of pixel wind in Contra“.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS 17, [`keyframeAnimator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/keyframeanimator(initialvalue:repeating:content:keyframes:)) is available. You can specify the keyframes using that.

Based on your existing code, you seem to want the heart to move linearly to y offsets -10, -20, -10, and then back to 0. Each move takes 0.3 seconds, and waits for 0.7 seconds between moves. Here is the code with `keyframeAnimator`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("❤️")
            .font(.system(size: 200,weight: .bold))
            .keyframeAnimator(initialValue: 0 as CGFloat, repeating: true) { content, value in
                content.offset(y: value)
            } keyframes: { _ in
                KeyframeTrack {
                    LinearKeyframe(-10, duration: 0.3)
                    LinearKeyframe(-10, duration: 0.7)
                    LinearKeyframe(-20, duration: 0.3)
                    LinearKeyframe(-20, duration: 0.7)
                    LinearKeyframe(-10, duration: 0.3)
                    LinearKeyframe(-10, duration: 0.7)
                    LinearKeyframe(0, duration: 0.3)
                    LinearKeyframe(0, duration: 0.7)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

> If I want to specify any view to animate in a method, what should I do?

SwiftUI doesn't work imperatively like UIKit. If you want to reuse this code, you can extract it as a view modifier:

```
extension View {
    func animateUpAndDown() -> some View {
        self.keyframeAnimator(initialValue: 0 as CGFloat, repeating: true) { content, value in
            content.offset(y: value)
        } keyframes: { _ in
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

To use this, just add `.animateUpAndDown()` like a normal view modifier at the end of the view you want to animate.

Comment: Bro thank you very very very much. Is there any way below iOS17?

Comment: @user23194465 you can just use your code in the question. It looks ugly, but that’s life.